# is the voltage drop of a battery that is being short circuited the same as the battery's advertised voltige

Tags: electricity, voltage, short-circuits

So I know this is a pretty fundamental question, but I'll ask it any way. lets say you have a 12V battery, and the positive is connected to the negative directly by a wire with negligible resistance... is the voltage drop between the positive terminal and the negative terminal still 12V without a resistor? I know this is a short circuit by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, quite opposite.  For short-cut between both terminals, voltage drop between terminals is exactly 0 V!  All of the advertised voltage drop is on the internal resistor of the battery.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

As a slightly more elaborate model, the voltage drop between the terminals will not be *exactly* zero. You can model the situation as a voltage source $V_0$ in series with a big resistor (the battery's internal resistor) $R$ and a small resistor $r$ (the wire). The voltage drop across the wire is then $V_0r/R$, which is of course very close to zero.

Comment: Indeed, but question was *negligible* resistance, so I've used that assumption :)